# Not enough storage available to complete this operation

Tags: pagefile

I am facing a wierd error whenever I tried to click any mmc like server manger etc its gives this error

Not enough storage available to complete this operation

Any suggestions how to resolve this...???

Comment: Could you be (a lot) be more specific. Provide information about Windows version, MMC version, updates installed. While gathering all this, please check that your hard drive is not actually full.

Comment: The OS is Win server 2008 r2 , the hd is not full.

Comment: Have you updated MMC or anything lately? If you try to manually install MMC on a Windows which already has MMC, it [may cause problems](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa722a8b-feb2-49eb-8242-b93f45005f2f/mmc-30-error-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command?forum=windowsserver2008r2general). You could also try to remove MMC cache from `%APPDATA%\microsoft\mmc`.

Comment: The mmc is not opening how am I supposed to see its version.....
any suggestions for that , I have cleared the cache of mmc in appdata but still the error comes whenever I click on server manger or any other mmc "Not enough storage available to complete this operation."